# HTL conditional rendering while not affecting nested html

Tags: html, conditional-statements, aem, sightly

Is it possible using HTL to *not* render a HTML element if a condition evaluates to `false` but still render the nested content? Example:

```
<A renderIf="${properties.value}">
   <B>my content</B>
</A>
```

If value is `false` then this would be rendered:

```
<B>my content</B>
```

If value is `true` this should be rendered:

```
<A>
   <B>my content</B>
</A>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is exactly what [`data-sly-unwrap`](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/experience-manager-htl/using/htl/block-statements.html#unwrap) is for:

```html
<A data-sly-unwrap="${!properties.value}">
   <B>my content</B>
</A>
```

(note the inverted condition wrt your example because when data-sly-unwrap evaluates to true, it will unwrap the element, i.e. only display the contents).

Comment: I feel like blind-folded for not having seen this in the docs, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Condition based displaying in HTML is possible with something called `templates`. Basically what template does is to hide anything that is inside the tags, and display them when a condition turns out to be true. You need support of `Javascript` to achieve this.

Example:

```js
function validate() {
  if (document.getElementById("userInput").value == "EXAMPLE ANSWER") {
    var temp = document.getElementsByTagName("template")[0]; // Give the correct index of template when you have more than 1 template tag
    var cloneNode = temp.content.cloneNode(true);
    document.body.appendChild(cloneNode);
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="userInput" value="EXAMPLE ANSWER"/>
<button onclick="validate()">Validate</button>

<template>
  <h2>That's the right answer!</h2>
</template>
```

Comment: Thank you, Deepak, for your solution. However, ``unwrap`` seems to do the trick quite effortlessly.